# JSF rich:suggestionbox need to filter the suggestion list by excluding the items already selected

Tags: jsf, richfaces

There is a jsf suggestion box associated with a text box. all is working fine except that i am unable to exclude the results that are already selected. the associated text box contains comma separated values. i have not found any way to make it possible to show suggestions excluding the ones already present in the text box. can i pass the text box value along-with the suggestion ajax request or any other idea?

```
public class ActionBean {

private String contacts;

public List<Contact> autocomplete(Object suggest) {

//....
// logic to get the list from DB based on suggestion but no data about existing selected values
//....

}
}
```

JSF's xhtml portion of that text box and suggestion box

```
<h:inputText value="#{actionBean.contacts}" styleClass="input mFields" id="text">
    <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{someaction...}" return;" reRender="..."/>
</h:inputText>

<h:outputLabel value="Search and Select Name/Number or Enter Number. Use , for multiple entries"/>
    <rich:suggestionbox limitToList="true" id="suggestionBoxId" for="text" tokens=",[]" suggestionAction="#{actionBean.autocomplete}" var="result" fetchValue="#{result.number}" height="100" width="200" nothingLabel="No contacts found" columnClasses="center" usingSuggestObjects="true" >
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{result.name} #{result.lastName}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{result.number}" style="font-style:italic" />
        </h:column>
    </rich:suggestionbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass the selected values to the server in order to exclude them. Maybe you could do some JavaScript hack, but it would not be much cleaner (see usingSuggestObjects and onobjectchange).

Answer (score 0):

@Chris thanks for the response.

i have finally found the way i.e the bean that was being used was set to request scope so even calling the onchange event through javasript was creating method calls per request per bean. In the above case, suggestionbox was calling on a new object everytime and onchange on the inputtext was calling on a new object everytime as well.

The solution I came up with was that I set the bean scope to 'view' so that for that view the bean object remains the same and hence all requests can share the state. then calling onchange event of inputtext in the onsubmit event of the suggestionbox which updates the bean field with latest value in the inputtext.

```
<rich:suggestionbox limitToList="true" id="suggestionBoxId" for="text" tokens=",[]" suggestionAction="#{actionBean.autocomplete}" var="result" fetchValue="#{result.number}" height="100" width="200" nothingLabel="No contacts found" columnClasses="center" usingSuggestObjects="true" onsubmite="call onchange event on inputext field">
```

Hope it helps.